# kcfinder + Ckeditor неизвестная ошибка

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

при загрузке фото или обновлении загрузчика пишет "неизвестная ошибка"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: минус то за что?

Comment: права на папку в которую загружаете есть ?

Comment: да поставил 777 для теста